# WPF - Turn stackpanel 180° and stay in the same place

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So my question is pretty simple:

I have a StackPanel with two objects: a button and an rectangle (which is filled with an image by clicking the button). Now, an additional thing that has to happen is when the button is clicked, the entire stackpanel has to be flipped upside down AND it has to stay in the same place.

I have tried with the RenderTransformOrigin-property set on "0.5,0.5"
but I haven't got any luck with this .. either the stackpanel moved to another location or it disappeared (out of bounds)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>
       <StackPanel Name="pnlFlip" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
           <Button Content="Test" Margin="200,78,197,-78" Name="btnTest" Click="btnTest_Click" Height="30"/>
           <Rectangle Margin="175,146,162,-239" Name="rectTest" Fill="Red" Height="127"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code for my buttons is like this:

```
private int scale = 1;
private int angle = 180;

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
    img.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Images/logo.jpg"));
    rectTest.Fill = img;
    //Trying a ScaleTranfsformObject
    ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
    if(scale == 1)
    {
        scale = -1;
        st.ScaleY = scale;
    }
    else
    {
        scale = 1;
        st.ScaleY = scale;
    }
    //Trying a RotateTransform Object
    RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
    if(angle == 180)
    {
        rt.Angle = angle;
        angle += 180;
    }
    else
    {
        rt.Angle = angle;
        angle -= 180;
    }
    pnlFlip.RenderTransform = rt;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong/how do I fix this?

Comment: Copy-pasted your code into a new project and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using storyboard is better approach than setting this directly in code in click handler. You will get smooth changes in UI.

Following will achieve your objective with XAML only, without any code behind. Setting `RenderTransformOrigin` in the `StackPanel` is what keeps it in the center after running the rotate transform.

To activate the animation on click, we just add a Button.Trigger handler which has storyboard on DoubleAnimation to change the angle to 180 degree in the StackPanel. Rest of the XAML is what you had before.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="pnlFlip" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">           
    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform />
    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    <Button Content="Test" Margin="200,78,197,-78" Name="btnTest" Height="30">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="180" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlFlip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"  />                               
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Rectangle Margin="175,146,162,-239" Name="rectTest" Fill="Red" Height="127"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me and with the animation, it was even better! Thanks a lot! But now I've got an extension on my assignment, I've got to pull the same trick on a Grid .. Flip the entire grid 180°, same concept like this one

Comment: Give the Grid a name, add RenderTransform node after the grid. Then add another DoubleAnimation node inside the storyboard. In the StoryBoard.TargetName, set it equal to the name of the Grid's name.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my computer (minus the code for the image in your Resources.)

Here's how it looks when the application launches:
[image]

And here's how it looks after I click the button:
[image]

Which part of this falls short of your intentions?

Note that you can use a ternary operator to remove your conditional branches and cut down on code, like so:

```
angle = angle == 180 ? 0 : 180;
rt.Angle = angle;
```

Comment: Well, when I tried this, the first time I clicked the button, my entire stackpanel went out of bounds. Maybe something with my Visual Studio that bugged.